# CL login fails (skips Password field)

Tags: command-line, 18.04, login

The following Problem occurred. If i try to login per CL (pressed Ctrl+Alt+F1), i can enter my Username after pressing enter it skips the pw field and after 3 sec. it tells me login incorrect. After that it skips the login field and tells me login incorrect for 4 more times.

```
Ubuntu 18...

Laptop-01 login: asd
Password:

Login incorrect
Laptop-01 login:

Login incorrect
Laptop-01 login:

Login incorrect
...
```

I can login per GUI and access everything, switch Users in the shell ...

Comment: This is a known kernel bug. A fix is already developed and in testing (-proposed repositories). It should hit the regular repositories in the next couple of days or weeks. For the time being, you can boot an older kernel version instead through the GRUB menu and "Advanced options for Ubuntu"